# --How to implement req.body.param validation

Tags: node.js

Newbie question here pls.
am trying to validate the value of MAXDEPTH below.
if it is greater than x or less than y, execute the function updateMaxdepth().
Otherwise print error saying input value out of bounds.
I do have express-validator installed.
Just can not figure out how to implement in the code below.
Thank you for your help !!

============================================================

```
app.post('/submit', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
var QMGR      = req.body.qmgr;
var APP_ID    = req.body.app_id;
var QUEUE     = req.body.queue;
var CURDEPTH  = parseInt(req.body.curdepth);
var MAXDEPTH  = parseInt(req.body.maxdepth);

var bash = {cmd_1: `su mqm -c dspmq | grep ${QMGR}`,
cmd_2: `su mqm -c 'echo \"dis queue(${QUEUE}) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}' | grep MAX |grep -v dis| perl -lanF\"[()]\" -e 'print $F[1]'`,
cmd_3: `su mqm -c 'echo \"dis queue(${QUEUE}) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}' | grep MAX |grep -v dis| perl -lanF\"[()]\" -e 'print $F[3]'`,
cmd_4: `su mqm -c 'echo \"alt ql(${QUEUE}) maxdepth(${MAXDEPTH})\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}'`}

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({host: 'smtp.qcorpaa.aa.com',
port: 25,
//port: 587,
secure: false,
tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
//tls: { ciphers:'SSLv3' }});

function updateMaxdepth() {var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_4, function(err, stdout, stderr) {if (stdout.includes('changed')){var mailOptions = {
from: 'root@esmqst15',
to: 'DL_Enterprise_MQ@aa.com',
subject: 'Maxdepth Updated for queue '+req.body.queue+' on QMGR '+req.body.qmgr,
text: 'Maxdepth Updated for queue '+req.body.queue+' to '+req.body.maxdepth+' on QMGR '+req.body.qmgr+' by App_ID '+req.body.app_id
};
console.log(mailOptions);
transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err)
} else {
  console.log(info);
}}}});
```

Comment: You can do it in the function with if statement: ```if(req.body.param > x ||  req.body.param < y) { //do something } else { return reject }``` if you need more detailed answer let me know

Comment: Thank you Elnatan.. so I was thinking of inserting the if..else conditional  and if true execute updateMaxdepth() function. This is where i am not sure how to do.. if you can show me a code example.. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

code example (should look something like this)

```
app.post('/submit', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
var QMGR      = req.body.qmgr;
var APP_ID    = req.body.app_id;
var QUEUE     = req.body.queue;
var CURDEPTH  = parseInt(req.body.curdepth);
var MAXDEPTH  = parseInt(req.body.maxdepth);

var bash = {cmd_1: `su mqm -c dspmq | grep ${QMGR}`,
cmd_2: `su mqm -c 'echo \"dis queue(${QUEUE}) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}' | grep MAX |grep -v dis| perl -lanF\"[()]\" -e 'print $F[1]'`,
cmd_3: `su mqm -c 'echo \"dis queue(${QUEUE}) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}' | grep MAX |grep -v dis| perl -lanF\"[()]\" -e 'print $F[3]'`,
cmd_4: `su mqm -c 'echo \"alt ql(${QUEUE}) maxdepth(${MAXDEPTH})\" | runmqsc ${QMGR}'`}

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({host: 'smtp.qcorpaa.aa.com',
port: 25,
//port: 587,
secure: false,
tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
//tls: { ciphers:'SSLv3' }});

if(req.body.param > x ||  req.body.param < y) {
 updateMaxdepth()
} else {
 return res.status(400).json({msg:'not valid'})
}

function updateMaxdepth() {var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_4, function(err, stdout, stderr) {if (stdout.includes('changed')){var mailOptions = {
from: 'root@esmqst15',
to: 'DL_Enterprise_MQ@aa.com',
subject: 'Maxdepth Updated for queue '+req.body.queue+' on QMGR '+req.body.qmgr,
text: 'Maxdepth Updated for queue '+req.body.queue+' to '+req.body.maxdepth+' on QMGR '+req.body.qmgr+' by App_ID '+req.body.app_id
};
console.log(mailOptions);
transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err)
} else {
  console.log(info);
}}}});
```